# I have a JavaScript parameter, which references an object. How to change the referenced object to a string, instead of changing my local variable?

Tags: javascript, json

I wrote a custom i18n function, which allows me to define JSON translations in the following way:

```
  var myJson =   {
       "home" : {
          "title" : { "nl" : "Hoofdmenu",
                      "de" : "Hauptmenü",
                      "en" : "Main menu"}
      }
    }
```

I also wrote a function, in which I insert my JSON, and then I want to overwrite the language part with the actual language:

```
function LanguagePropertySetter(obj, lang){
  if (!obj){
    return;
  }

  if (typeof obj !== "object"){
    return;
  }

  var keys = Object.keys(obj);

  if (!keys){
    return;
  }

  if (keys.indexOf(lang) !== -1){
      obj= obj[lang];  // <------ THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
      LanguagePropertySetter(obj[keys[i]], lang);
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

When I call the function like this:

```
var translatedJson = LanguagePropertySetter(myJson, "en");
```

This is what I want my result to look like:

```
var translatedJson = {
       "home" : {
          "title" : "Main menu"
      }
    }
```

But this is what I end up with:

```
 var translatedJson =   {
       "home" : {
          "title" : { "nl" : "Hoofdmenu",
                      "de" : "Hauptmenü",
                      "en" : "Main menu"}
      }
    }
```

If I write the following, it seems that my local reference to the parameter `obj` instead becomes a reference to a string called `'Main menu'`. If I were to change the line to

```
obj.translation = obj[lang]
```

It does exactly what I expect, it changes my JSON to:

```
 {
       "home" : {
          "title" : { "nl" : "Hoofdmenu",
                      "de" : "Hauptmenü",
                      "en" : "Main menu",
                      "translation" : "Main menu"}
      }
    }
```

But I do not want this. How can I change my object `obj` to a string?

Comment: do you like to call it recursive and change the last property before the language property are found?

Comment: You're recursing, but your `obj` variable is replaced with a local one each time: when you call `LanguagePropertySetter(obj[keys[i]], lang)` without assigning the return value to anything, it's not the same `obj` anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is, you assign a value to a local variable. To break it down:

You have an object, and a variable with an object reference.

```
var test = { level0: { level1: 42 } },
    temp = test.level0;
```

Now you assign a value to temp.

```
temp = 'foo';
```

The result is an unchanged object `test` and a variable `temp` with a new value `'foo'`.

The reference to the object is replaced with a new value.

```js
var test = { level0: { level1: 42 } },
    temp = test.level0;

console.log(temp); // { level1: 42 }
temp = 'foo';
console.log(temp); // 'foo'
console.log(test); // { level0: { level1: 42 } }
```

To overcome the problem, you need an object and a key and a value you like to change. Then you keep the reference of the object and change only the property. The variable `temp` has still the reference to the assigned object.

```js
var test = { level0: { level1: { level2: 42 } } },
    key = 'level1',
    temp = test.level0;

temp[key] = 'bar';
console.log(temp); // { level1: 'bar' }
console.log(test); // { level0: { level1: 'bar' } }
```

You could use a recursive, iterative approach with a deep look to the wanted property.

```js
function iter(object, key) {
    return Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        if (!object[k] || typeof object[k] !== 'object') {
            return;
        }
        if (key in object[k]) {
            object[k] = object[k][key];
            return;
        }
        iter(object[k], key);
    });
}


var object = { report: { title: { nl: "Rapportage", de: "Rapportage DE", en: "Rapportage EN" } }, searchmachine: { title: { nl: "Machine zoeken", de: "Machine zoeken DE", en: "Machine zoeken EN" }, Systeemnaam: { nl: "Systeemnaam", de: "Systeemnaam DE", en: "Systeemnaam EN" }, plaats: { nl: "plaats", de: "plaats DE", en: "plaats EN" }, macaddress: { nl: "macaddress", de: "macaddress DE", en: "macaddress EN" } } };

iter(object, "en");
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Even better because of generic upside.

Comment: Nina, thank you for this nice answer. I gave it an upvote because of the generic setup and the great explanation. However, it doesn't seem to work on nested structure the same way Fissio's answer does. If you are interested, I will provide you with the full JSON on which it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @DaniëlCamps, yes, please provide the structure, i will have a look.

Comment: @DaniëlCamps, it was a problem with early return and `some`, because i thought only one item has to be to change. now it should work.

Comment: Ah, cool :) I now changed your answer to the best answer due to the generic set-up

Answer (score 1):

Here's a iterative + recursive translating solution, and a plunker to demonstrate (check the browser console).

```
function LanguagePropertySetter(obj, lang){
  if (!obj){
    return;
  }

  if (typeof obj !== "object"){
    return;
  }

  function translateChildren(iterObj) {
    if (typeof iterObj !== 'object') return iterObj;
    var keys = Object.keys(iterObj);
    if (keys.indexOf(lang) > -1) {
      return iterObj[lang]
    }
    else {
      for (var key in iterObj) {
        iterObj[key] = translateChildren(iterObj[key])
      }
    }
    return iterObj;
  }
  return translateChildren(obj);
}

var translatedJson = LanguagePropertySetter(myJson, "en");
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/uMRLAKUSUBFoOQQWDbqZ?p=preview